# Using JScript for uninstall script

Tags: installation, jscript, wsh, windows-scripting

I am building an installer in VS2010 and want a script to run after uninstall (to remove license files). I have found JScript as a scripting language for Windows 7 and have implemented a simple script to delete a directory (which works fine):

```
var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

var result = wshShell.Popup("Remove license?", 0, "Remove license?", 4);

if (result == 6) {
    var license_dir = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramData%");

    license_dir += "\\<my product>";

    var fso;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    if (fso.FolderExists(license_dir)) {
        fso.DeleteFolder(license_dir, true);
    } else {
        WScript.Echo(license_dir + " didn't exist. Nothing removed.");
    }
}
```

My question is, is this a valid and (more importantly) portable way of doing this?

Comment: Is it an MSI-based installer? I mean if the output is MSI file?

Comment: Yes, the result is an MSI installer. I use Visual Studio 2010's "Visual Studio Installer" project template to create it.